# Switch statement returning null

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to implement a grading system for a test using an enum and a switch statement, however with the current code I have the result is always "null". I can't see where iv'e gone wrong, can anyone help?

```
public enum Grade {
    A, B, C, D, E, U; 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the students mark:");
    int points = scan.nextInt();

    if (points < 0 || points > 200) {
        System.out.println("Error! points must be between 0 & 200");
    } else {
       System.out.println(findGrade(points));
    }

}

public static Grade findGrade(int points) {
    switch (points) {
        case 1:
            if (points>= 0 && points <= 59) {
                return Grade.valueOf("U");
            }
        case 2:
            if (points >= 60 && points <= 89) {
                return Grade.valueOf("E");
            }
        case 3:
            if (points >= 90 && points <= 119) {
                return Grade.valueOf("D");
            }
        case 4:
            if (points >= 110 && points <= 139) {
                return Grade.valueOf("C");
            }
        case 5:
            if (points >= 140 && points <= 169) {
                return Grade.valueOf("B");
            }
            case 6:
            if (points >= 170 && points <= 200) {
                return Grade.valueOf("A");
            }
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: So if `points` is equals to 2, you're checking `if (points >= 60 && points <= 89)`. Do you think this is logic ?

Comment: What's the point of that switch statement?

Comment: still need break; for each case see my answer below

Comment: What's the point of that comment @Artur?

Comment: @jwg: Read answer of 'Zong Zheng Li' and you'll know ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at

```
switch (points) {
   case 1:
      if (points >= 0 && points <= 59) {
          return Grade.valueOf("U");
      }
```

What you're basically saying is:

```
if (points == 1) {
    if (points >= 0 && points <= 59) {
        return Grade.valueOf("U");
    }
}
```

which is nonsense. I don't think you need switch at all in this case. Just use:

```
if (points < 0) {
    return null;
}
if (points <= 59) {
    return Grade.valueOf("U");
}
if (points <= 89) {
    return Grade.valueOf("E");
}
if (points <= 119)
    return Grade.valueOf("D");
}
...
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

While switching on an `int` type variable say `points`, the code corresponding to a case `n` is executed, when the value of `points` is `n`. I guess you can now understand where the mistake is. Currently, none of your cases would match the value of `points`, if it is greater than `6`, so the value will be `null`.

It is clear that you want to implement cases such that those are executed for various ranges. One way to implement this is by narrowing a larger range to smaller range, so that writing cases for them is easier for you. For example, the range `[0, 59]` can be narrowed to `[0, 5]` by dividing `points` by `10`. Similarly for other ranges, you can narrow them, and write cases like these:

```
public static Grade findGrade(int points) {
    int val = points / 10;

    switch (val) {
        // 0 <= points <= 59 is same as 0 <= val <= 5
        case 0: case 1: 
        case 2: case 3: 
        case 4: case 5: return Grade.valueOf("U");

        // 60 <= points <= 89 is same as 6 <= val <= 8
        case 6: case 7: 
        case 8:         return Grade.valueOf("E");

        // like so
    }
}
```

Comment: A bad idea IMHO - the right answer is just not to use `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a switch at all. Simply put your `if`s in a chain, and that would work for you:

```
if (points>= 0 && points <= 59) {
    return Grade.valueOf("U");
}
if (points >= 60 && points <= 89) {
    return Grade.valueOf("E");
}
if (points >= 90 && points <= 119) {
    return Grade.valueOf("D");
}
if (points >= 110 && points <= 139) {
    return Grade.valueOf("C");
}
if (points >= 140 && points <= 169) {
    return Grade.valueOf("B");
}
if (points >= 170 && points <= 200) {
    return Grade.valueOf("A");
}
return null;
```

The idea behind the `switch` statement is to let you base a decision on a set of fixed values or small value ranges. In this case, however, the range is pretty large, so a chain of `if` statements looks like a more appropriate choice.

Considering the task that you are implementing, you could build a shorter solution with a lookup table and a loop:

```
int[] limits = new int[] {59, 89, 119, 139, 169, 200};
String[] grades = new String[] {"U", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"};
for (int i = 0 ; i != limits.length ; i++)
    if (points <= limits[i])
         return grades[i];
return null;
```